# Analysis of Wheatstone Bridge circuit with connected output terminals

Tags: circuit-analysis, wheatstone-bridge

I am given the following case of a Wheatstone Bridge circuit where the output Terminals \$U_{a}\$ and \$U_{b}\$ are connected with a wire and need to derive both output voltages as functions of the Resistances in the circuit.

[image]

Since they are connected, the output voltages should be the same but does the Voltage division rule still hold? Is it the case that \$U_{a} = \frac{R_{1}}{R + R_1} * U_{in}\$,
\$U_{b} = \frac{R_{1}}{R + R_1} * U_{in}\$ ?

Comment: There are two voltage dividers in parallel. So find the equivalent voltage divider.

Comment: @Circuitfantasist Ah I see now, I can simplify the voltage dividers and resistances then get my equations that way.

Comment: By the way, I don't see much sense in this question. A more interesting task would be to find that R where it does not matter whether "a" and "b" are connected or separated ("balanced bridge").

Answer (score 1):

Well, we have the following circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fCnbsa.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The input resistance can be found:

$$\text{R}_\text{in}=\frac{\left(\text{R}_1+\text{R}_2\right)\left(\text{R}_3+\text{R}_4\right)}{\text{R}_1+\text{R}_2+\text{R}_3+\text{R}_4}\tag1$$

Now, the input current is given by:

$$\text{I}_\text{in}=\frac{\text{V}_\text{in}}{\text{R}_\text{in}}=\text{V}_\text{in}\cdot\frac{\text{R}_1+\text{R}_2+\text{R}_3+\text{R}_4}{\left(\text{R}_1+\text{R}_2\right)\left(\text{R}_3+\text{R}_4\right)}\tag2$$

Now, the current \$\text{I}_1\$ is given by:

$$\text{I}_1=\frac{\text{R}_3+\text{R}_4}{\text{R}_1+\text{R}_2+\text{R}_3+\text{R}_4}\cdot\text{I}_\text{in}=\frac{\text{V}_\text{in}}{\text{R}_1+\text{R}_2}\tag3$$

Now, the current \$\text{I}_2\$ is given by:

$$\text{I}_2=\frac{\text{R}_1+\text{R}_2}{\text{R}_1+\text{R}_2+\text{R}_3+\text{R}_4}\cdot\text{I}_\text{in}=\frac{\text{V}_\text{in}}{\text{R}_3+\text{R}_4}\tag4$$

So, we get:

- $$\text{V}_\text{A}=\text{I}_1\cdot\text{R}_2=\frac{\text{V}_\text{in}\text{R}_2}{\text{R}_1+\text{R}_2}\tag5$$
- $$\text{V}_\text{B}=\text{I}_2\cdot\text{R}_4=\frac{\text{V}_\text{in}\text{R}_4}{\text{R}_3+\text{R}_4}\tag6$$

So, we also get:

$$\text{V}_\text{A}-\text{V}_\text{B}=\text{V}_\text{in}\cdot\left\{\frac{\text{R}_2}{\text{R}_1+\text{R}_2}-\frac{\text{R}_4}{\text{R}_3+\text{R}_4}\right\}\tag7$$

Comment: This would be true only if Va = Vb because A and B are connected.